# Prove $\mathbb{A}_i^n$ is dense in $\mathbb{P}^n$. affine space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathbb{P}^n = \bigcup_{i=0}^n \mathbb{A}_i^n$, where each $\mathbb{A}_i^n$ is an affine space $\mathbb{A}_i^n = \mathbb{A}^n$.

Prove $\mathbb{A}_i^n$ is dense in $\mathbb{P}^n$.

attempt: Suppose $\mathbb{P}^n = \bigcup_{i=0}^n \mathbb{A}_i^n$. Then by definition $\mathbb{A}_i^n$ is called dense in $\mathbb{P}^n$ if $\mathbb{\bar A}_i^n =\mathbb{P}^n $, where $\mathbb{\bar A}_i^n$ is the closure of $\mathbb{A}_i^n$ , and is the smallest closed set of $\mathbb{P}^n$ that contains $\mathbb{A}_i^n$. Then our goal is to show  $\mathbb{\bar A}_0^n = \mathbb{P}^n$ since we can take the union of finitely many affine spaces, and $\mathbb{P}^n $ can be equal to either one. Then we see the set $\mathbb{A}_0^n \subset \mathbb{P}^n$  as of points $a = (a_0,...,a_n)$ for which $a_0 \neq 0$ where it's open. And its point can be put into a one to one correspondence with the points of an $n$ dimensional affine space by letting $\alpha_i = a_i/a_0 $ for all $i = 1,...,n$ and sending $a \in \mathbb{A}_0^n$ to $(a_1,..,,a_n) \in \mathbb{A}^n$.

I am not sure how to approach this problem . Can someone please help me and give me some feedback? Thank you!

Comment: Suppose $\mathbb{A}_i^n$ is not dense.  Then, there is some $\mathbb{A}_j^n$ where the closure of $\mathbb{A}_i^n\cap\mathbb{A}_j^n$ in $\mathbb{A}_j^n$ is not all of $\mathbb{A}_j^n$.  Prove that this is not possible.

Comment: Related: [Denseness in $\mathbb{P}^n$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119602/a-question-about-denseness-in-mathbbpn?rq=1).

Comment: So we want to show $\mathbb{A_i}^n$ is not dense in $\mathbb{P}^n$ and choose an element $a \in \mathbb{P}^n -\mathbb{A_i}^n$ and find an open set $\mathbb{A_j}^n$ containing $a$ and not intersecting $\mathbb{A_j}^n$?

Comment: It's a contradiction based proof.  So, that's what you're trying to do, but it can't happen.

Comment: this is literally the same argument as in the link for denseness in P^n you linked, but only assume that the $\mathbb{A}_i^n$ is not dense and then show we can't have that each open subset can intersect a value $a \in \mathbb{P^n}\{v\mathbb{A}_i^n}$? and so we have the contradiction?

Comment: Yes, I wrote my hint and then saw the link with the answer.  There are different ways to get the contradiction (or to prove the statement directly), but they amount to the same thing of showing that an intersection must exist.